# Как несколько файлов записать в один JSON файл?

Tags: json, python-3.x

Есть 2-а файла `one.cfg`, `two.cfg`.

Как закодировать эти 2-а файла в один `files.json`?

Comment: Поясните на примере, что есть и что Вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: Проголосуйте за ответ пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала загружаем содержимое наших 2 файлов, а затем загружаем их в json структуру, потом открываем новый файл куда будем сохранять и при помощи команды `dump` сохраняем, всё просто :)

```
import json

a = open('one.cfg', 'r')
b = open('two.cfg', 'r')

data = {
   'one.cfg' : a.read(),
   'two.cfg' : b.read(),
}

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(data, f)
```